# Which are the top legendary sets for each class?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo II each class had its class-specific gold set: the [Immortal King](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/sets/sets5.shtml#immortalking) for the Barbarian, [Trang-Oul's Avatar](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/sets/sets7.shtml#trangouls) for the Necromancer, and so on.

Is there something similar in Diablo III? If so, are the informations for all the sets already available?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Each class has two level 60 sets limited to them - one occupying the primary and secondary hands, and the other occupying 5 item slots (or 6 for the Barbarian's Immortal King set). Below is the list of them all. Notice that the larger sets only require 4 items (or 5 for the Immortal King) to get the full set bonuses.

Consider using [this tooltip-enabling script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3399/diablo-iiis-tooltip-script-for-gaming-stack-exchange) to enable tooltips on this answer :)

### Post-1.0.4 class-specific sets:

#### Barbarian:

- Bul-Kathos's Glory:
  [1-Handed Mighty Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-solemn-vow),
  [1-Handed Mighty Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-warrior-blood)
- Immortal King's Legend:
  [Mighty Belt](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-tribal-binding),
  [Gloves](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-irons),
  [Boots](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-stride),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-eternal-reign),
  [2-Handed Mighty Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-boulder-breaker),
  [Helm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-triumph)

#### Demon Hunter:

- Danetta's Creed:
  [Hand Crossbow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/danettas-revenge),
  [Hand Crossbow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/danettas-spite)
- Natalya's Solace:
  [Helm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-sight),
  [Ring](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-reflection),
  [Hand Crossbow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-slayer),
  [Cloak](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-embrace),
  [Boots](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-bloody-footprints)

#### Monk:

- Shenlong's Noble Path:
  [Fist Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/shenlongs-fist-of-legend),
  [Fist Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/shenlongs-relentless-assault)
- Inna's Grandeur:
  [Belt](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-favor),
  [Pants](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-temperance),
  [Daibo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-reach),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-vast-expanse),
  [Spirit Stone](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-radiance)

#### Witch Doctor:

- Manajuma's Ornaments:
  [Ceremonial Knife](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/manajumas-carving-knife),
  [Mojo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/manajumas-gory-fetch)
- Zunimassa's Whispers:
  [Voodoo Mask](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-vision),
  [Mojo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-string-of-skulls),
  [Boots](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-trail),
  [Ring](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-pox),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-marrow)

#### Wizard:

- Chantodo's Return:
  [Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/chantodos-force),
  [Wand](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/chantodos-will)
- Tal Rasha's Sacrifice:
  [Amulet](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-allegiance),
  [Belt](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-brace),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-relentless-pursuit),
  [Helm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-guise-of-wisdom),
  [Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-unwavering-glare)

---

And because they are still in circulation,

### Pre-1.0.4 class-specific sets:

#### Barbarian:

- Bul-Kathos's Children:
  [1-Handed Mighty Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-sacred-charge),
  [1-Handed Mighty Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-tribal-guardian)
- Immortal King:
  [Mighty Belt](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-detail),
  [Gloves](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-forge),
  [Boots](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-pillar),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-soul-cage),
  [2-Handed Mighty Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-stone-crusher),
  [Helm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-will)

#### Demon Hunter:

- Danetta's Oath:
  [Hand Crossbow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/danettas-fury),
  [Hand Crossbow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/danettas-rage)
- Natalya's Wrath:
  [Helm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-gaze),
  [Ring](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-mark),
  [Hand Crossbow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-redemption),
  [Cloak](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-shadow),
  [Boots](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-soul)

#### Monk:

- Shenlong's Defense:
  [Fist Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/shenlongs-crashing-tide),
  [Fist Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/shenlongs-endless-wave)
- Inna's Majesty:
  [Belt](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-blessing),
  [Pants](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-glory),
  [Daibo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-justice),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-refuge),
  [Spirit Stone](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-splendor)

#### Witch Doctor:

- Manajuma's Ritual:
  [Ceremonial Knife](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/manajumas-ritual-cutter),
  [Mojo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/manajumas-ritual-prize)
- Zunimassa's Spirit:
  [Voodoo Mask](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-attunement),
  [Mojo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-ferocity),
  [Boots](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-journey),
  [Ring](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-plague),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-vessel)

#### Wizard:

- Chantodo's Legacy:
  [Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/chantodos-elemental-seal),
  [Wand](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/chantodos-sacred-protector)
- Tal Rasha's Wrappings:
  [Amulet](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-adjudication),
  [Belt](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-finespun-cloth),
  [Chest Armor](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-guardianship),
  [Helm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-horadric-crest),
  [Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-lidless-eye)

Comment: Good job with the script :) It's really useful!

Comment: Holy mother of Imperius, the Monk's legendaries now actually look like Legendaries. I might go on a quest for those.

Comment: Thx fot the info, i saw the blizz database and there is just 1 set for the barbarian, the immortal king i dont know why the made just one, its sad, but well, hope they made more.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS ANSWER IS UPDATED FOR PATCH 2.0/REAPER OF SOULS**

There are new class-specific sets available in the new Reaper of Souls expansion. These items only drop in Torment I or higher difficulty.

Instead of re-posting, [you can find a well formatted list here](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10189299133), which will allow you to view the items in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a user made compendium already but you could certainly just check the blizzard item data base. If you pick a certain armor type, lets say head you can then select for what quality you want to look for and then go for set.

[Example for head armor set pieces](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/helm/#type=set)